# Какая структура для Laravel SPA проекта с авторизацией?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, api, spa

Задаюсь вопросом:
разрабатывая API на Laravel к которому обращается SPA веб, как лучше всего разделить вьюху для авторизации и личный кабинет?

Собирая all-in-one JS крайне не хотелось бы светить для неавторизованного пользователя эндпоинты личного кабинета.

Поэтому хочу в зависимости от наличия авторизации у пользователя выводить ту или иную вьюху: легкую с авторизацией или полноценную SPA.

Полагаю, что хранить это в `public/` в виде `private.php` & `public.php` не очень хорошая идея.

Другой вариант: чуть усложить сборку фронтенда и раскидывать эти два файла в `resources/views/`.

Какие еще варианты я упускаю?

Answer (score 2):

Раз у вас SPA и API то все должно быть отдельно. 
На клиентской стороне можете проверять в `run` в событии `$routeChangeStart` зарегистрирован ли пользователь и редиректить в личный кабинет.

Что бы незарегистрированому пользователя не был доступен клиентский код кабинета используйте `ocLazyLoad` - это ленивая загрузка модулей

Авторизацию делайте с помощью `JWT`

Comment: Однако с применением ocLazyLoad все равно можно дернуть код для кабинета вручную, подсмотрев URL. Верно?

Comment: можно, но сервер все равно не авторизует пользователя, и никаких прав ему не даст, если это клиент, то это и так ясно. Я у себя делаю именно так, все равно проверка на сервере.  Ну и уж если вы говорите про SPA, то это отдельное приложение которое общается с сервером через API. В этом и суть, код клиента у клиента

Comment: Темболее продвинутый юзер зарегистрируется, увидит запросы к API